# Bootstrap Modal: Content from html page does not show within the modal

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-ng-click

I have a created a button when you click it a modal appears.
Here is the code:

```
<li style="float: right;">
     <button id="myBtn" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="printDivModal('rollup-tab')">Modal Test</button>
</li>
```

In the js, the ng-click should open a model which contains data from stackModal.html
Here is the code in the js file:

```
$scope.printDivModal = function(divName) {
            console.log('opening pop up');
            var ModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                //animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'app/views/modals/stackedModal.html',
                size: 'lg',
                /*
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.name = 'top';  
                  }
                 */
            });
        }
```

Here is the code for the model (stackedModal.html):

```
 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">The Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Text inside the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

When I click the Model-Test button, all I see is a small white rectangle show on the screen.  Nothing appears from the stackedModal html page.  Why is this?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the message "opening pop up" in your console?

Comment: @StefanVilbrandt Yes I do

Comment: data-target attribute also not needed when using javascript model open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove modal wrappers div's, [bootstrap-modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/ui-router-resolves) does it for you.
You just need to put modal content:

stackedModal.html:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">The Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Text inside the modal.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```